# www.domain.com does not redirect to domain.com in Godaddy with Github Pages

Tags: github, dns, hosting, github-pages, cname

Here are the steps I took to link my github pages to a custom domain:

1. Create CNAME file in the root
2. In Godday, I added one `A` record that points to `192.30.252.153` and one `CNAME` with host `www` and value `rahmonov.github.io`

`rahmonov.me` is working but `www.rahmonov.me` does not redirect to `rahmonov.me`. Instead, it is giving me Github `404` page, saying:

```
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a matter of time. I just had to wait. There was something about it in the documentation but strangely one of the domains (rahmonov.me) started to work immediately.